# International EU layover: need advice

Tags: transit, eu, connecting-flights

First-time international flyer. Need help.

I am travelling from Mumbai, India to Lisbon, Portugal via CDG, Paris, France.

The ticket has been booked by  a travel agency. It's all on a single round-trip ticket with Air France. I had doubts regarding connection and transit time.

1. Air France 217 from Mumbai arrives at CDG at 7:35 am local time at terminal 2E. Flight to Lisbon is at 9:25 am at terminal 1. I will have to clear immigration and also walk to the other terminal within this time. Should I tell the travel agency to book a later flight (Air France at 1:45pm)?
2. On the return trip, Air France 1125 arrives at CDG from Lisbon at 9:00 am at terminal 2F and flight 218 to Mumbai is at 10:40 at terminal 2E. Since there will be no immigration check this time and terminals are closer, this one seems doable. Any opinions?

Comment: You will go through exit immigration in Paris before you can reach the gate for flight 218.  Still, you ought to be able to make it unless your flight from Lisbon is delayed.  But there's no need to rebook your outbound flight.  If you miss the connection, the airline will rebook you on the spot, free of charge.

Comment: @phoog Is exit immigration same as entry ? Or shorter ?

Comment: I haven't been in CDG in many years, I'm afraid.  I would guess somewhat shorter, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the return flight, there will be an immigration clearance in CDG, in Terminal 2E. The connection between 2F and 2E is done airside, and it is a long walk. but baring any delays, you should be fine -- I've done it myself.

On the way in, you will **not** walk to T1. You do not want that... You'll take the Blue Shuttle, and then the Green Shuttle:

[image]

More info [here](http://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/inter-terminal-shuttles). Morning flights are plenty, and the airport is quite busy, but you should be ok.